# c++, Is there any good solution for Message Sender to support send method about various type?

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns

I want to make MessageSender to support send method about various type and satisfy followings conditions.

condition A) 'send XXX Type Message' can be added later (=Easy to expand)

condition B) each sendXTypeMessage is called in other thread (=Each method needed to be thread independent)

first my thinking was followings

```
class MessageSender
    {
    public:
     sendATypeMessage(ATypeData)
     sendBTypeMessage(BTypeData)
     sendCTypeMessage(CTypeData)
     ...(it can be added other type later)
    }
```

But in case of this, when I want to add sendDTypeMessage(data). I have to modify MessageSender class.

---

second my thinking was  followings

```
class XTypeData : public IMessage
{
...
}
class MessageSender
{
public:
 sendMessage(const IMessage& data); 
}
MessageSender::sendMessage(const IMessage& data)
{
1) mutex lock
2) switch(check message type)
3) do something...
}
```

but in case of this, I have to use mutex lock in sendMessage.

then it can cause performance issue because each message sender thread can be blocked in sendMessage.

---

Is there any good solution to satisfy these conditions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can

1. have MessageSender implement different sending strategies (it can be based on MessageType, i.e: sendXXTypeMessage)
2. IMessage has a virtual send(MessageSender&) interface, each MessageType implements send() function, which calls relevant sending functions in MessageSender
3. MessageSender::sendMessage invokes the send() function of IMessage interface, which dynamically dispatches the call to the send() function of the concrete MessageType

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class MessageSender;
class IMessage{
    public:
    virtual void send(const MessageSender&)  = 0;
};

class ATypeData : public IMessage
{
    public:
    void send(const MessageSender& s) ; 
};

class BTypeData : public IMessage {
    public:
    void send(const MessageSender& s) ; 
};

class CTypeData : public IMessage {
    public:
    void send(const MessageSender& s) ; 
};

class MessageSender
{
public:
 void sendMessage(IMessage& data) { data.send(*this); }
 void sendATypeMessage(ATypeData&) const { /*mutex if needed*/ cout << "Sent A" << endl; }
 void sendBTypeMessage(BTypeData&) const { /*mutex if needed*/ cout << "Sent B" << endl; } 
 void sendCTypeMessage(CTypeData&) const { /*mutex if needed*/ cout << "Sent C" << endl; }
};

void ATypeData::send(const MessageSender& s)  { s.sendATypeMessage(*this); }
void BTypeData::send(const MessageSender& s)  { s.sendBTypeMessage(*this); }
void CTypeData::send(const MessageSender& s)  { s.sendCTypeMessage(*this); }

int main() {
    ATypeData a;
    BTypeData b;
    CTypeData c;
    MessageSender m;
    m.sendMessage(a);
    m.sendMessage(b);
    m.sendMessage(c);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

But your suggestion is not satisfy my 'condition B) each sendXTypeMessage is called in other thread (=Each method needed to be thread independent)'

ex) void sendATypeMessage(ATypeData&) const { mutex lock; while(1){ something delay in here}}

in case of this, I cannot call sendB/CTypeMessage method at the same time.

do you have any idea to solve this?

Comment: What is the critical section that mutex is supposed to protect? For example, if MessageSender holds a socket (which typically means one message is transmitted at a time until fully sent), then sendXXTypeMessage needs to wait until the previous sendXXTypeMessage is finished.  If it's socket, the design I posted above can be considered thread safe (surely it's missing socket initialization etc) Can you please elaborate the requirement of "thread independent"?

Comment: My purpose is each sendXTypeMessage can be called in other thread with very short frequency. (= it means 'thread independent') If I just use sendXTypeMessage, I can satisfy my purpose. but If I want to add sendDTypeMessage method, MessageSender class must be modified. So I looking for way to make extensible MessageSender class without modification to add sendXTypeMessage in the future. But I am not sure whether it is possible. and I don't know what is good design.